# How can I remove email addresses from Mail's autocomplete?

Tags: ipad

How do remove or erase the emails that I use befor on iPad email, they are not on my contacts. As soon I start typing one email address I get a bunch of old address..how can I erase or remove that.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same concern and from what I understand Apple does not provide a method to accomplish this cleanup. There are many threads in Apple Support discussion board and they always end suggesting to email Apple the request for this ability.

However, if you own a PC, this gem popped up:

[Can't delete Unwanted Email addresses, Auto-fill in saves them all !](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=13164988#13164988)

Comment: Just checking, is this still the case with iOS 5?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [a different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/81036/37797).

> Open Mail.app. In the bar up top click on **Window** and you'll see in the drop down menu **Previous Recipients** click on that and a list of emails opens up that your system uses as it's preferred email address. That means you get to type one or two letters and "it" fills in the rest of the wording for you.
>
> You have to erase these every time you enter in a new address for someone.
>
> Otherwise your system keeps putting in old addresses when you try to email someone even though you put in the correct email address into contacts and may even have erased the old addresses.

Answer (score 0):

When you start typing the email address, you get a list of suggested addresses. Tap on the circled i symbol on the right and then tap on „Remove from Recents“ at the bottom.